# preg_replace() laravel -Insert array in database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this error :
ErrorException in helpers.php line 748:
preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

SerialController.php

```
public function createSerial(Request $request)
    {
        $serial = new Serial();
        $serial->nume_serial = $request['numeSerial'];
        $serial->claritate = $request['claritate'];
        $serial->aparitie = $request['aparitie'];
        $serial->genuri = $request['genuri'];

        $serial->save();
        return redirect('/admin');
    }
```

view

```
<div class="checkbox">
                SF<input type="checkbox" name="genuri[1]" value="sf" id="">
            Biografic<input type="checkbox" name="genuri[2]" value="biografic" id="">
            Animat<input type="checkbox" name="genuri[3]" value="animat" id="">

        </div>
```

Comment: Strange. My `helpers.php` does not have any `preg_replace` inside. Did you change something in the framework?

Comment: @codedge, `helpers.php` has this line at 748 `$subject = preg_replace('/'.$search.'/', $value, $subject, 1);`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Which Laravel version? I am using the latest 5.2.x . You mean `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php`? Really strange, cannot see any preg_replace

Comment: @codedge, `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Thanks a lot! Wrong file ;)

Answer (score 1):

I guess a problem is you're trying to insert an array into a DB table.

```
$serial->genuri = $request['genuri']; // it's an array
```

You could convert an array to a json data:

```
$serial->genuri = json_encode($request['genuri']);
```

Of course you have to change `genuri` [data type to JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#writing-migrations):

```
$table->json('genuri');
```

Comment: FatalErrorException in SerialController.php line 19:
Call to a member function toJson() on array

Comment: migrate error :  [PDOException]
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error i
 n your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
  version for the right syntax to use near 'json not null) default character
  set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci' at line 1

Comment: So, you're trying to change `genuri` data type to `json` with new migration? Please share new migration code.

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('seriale', function (Blueprint $tableSeriale) {
            $tableSeriale->text('nume_serial');
            $tableSeriale->text('claritate');
            $tableSeriale->integer('aparitie');
            $tableSeriale->json('genuri');
        });
    }

Comment: It seems you're trying to create new table over existing one. If you want to use this way, you should rollback first. But I guess safer way is to create new migration and change one field only.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently from looking at your view, `$request['genuri']` is an array, and the error is this line `$serial->genuri = $request['genuri'];` since you are assigning an array to an object property that is string (I think?) in your DB table.

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, if you provide more info I might help more.

Comment: i want to insert two values in database in the same column